# What is the recognition code for the Howard families?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, world-as-myth

It's been a while since I've read much Heinlein, and I'm sure some will say I should be ashamed for not remembering this, but I remember there was a recognition code or greeting for members of the Howard families in Heinlein's works, but I can't remember what it was.

I think it started with something like, "The days are short," or something about life and days and one being short or long, but I can't remember the rest and it's not easily found with a search engine.

What is the recognition code the Howard families use?

Comment: Don't tell him!  Good grief!  We keep it secret for a reason! -- Ugh; now he'll be able to get into the meetings.. read the secret bulletin board.. get discounts at our Family Stores... *sigh*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The call and response was:

Caller: Life is short.

Responder: But the years are long.

Caller: Not while the evil days come not.

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me crazy and once I read it, I knew it was right.

Comment: It's mentioned in *Methuselah's Children* and *Time Enough for Love*.